# Как правильно перенести базу данных MySql Wordpress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Обычно переносил сайты на wordpress путем копирования файлов и дампа базы данных с заменой url в самой, бд и правкой wp-config. Но сейчас потребовалось один сайт перебросить на локальный сервер и поработать над ним, как при проделывании этих операций весь сайт поплыл, все блоки, слайдер отказался работать и пр.

Порывшись в гугле, нашел отличный скрипт для "правильной" правки бд: `Safe Search and Replace on Database with Serialized`. И вроде бы все должно было быть супер, но я никак не пойму что я упустил?

Скопировал файлы wordpress на OpenServer, поправил wp-config, бд не трогал, все как есть импортировал в новую бд, затем запустил скрипт и ввел замену url на локальный. После всех операций сайт все равно открывается по старым url из инета, а не на локалке. Подскажите где я туплю?

P.S. Подсказали тут сделать дамп бд на рабочем сайте, потом в админке поменять адрес сайта, потом снова сделать дамп, и сверху залить предыдущий, но теперь и ориг. сайт перестал работать.

Comment: Все, сайт на хостинге восстановил, теперь вот с первым вопросом разобраться бы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> P.S. Подсказали тут сделать дамп бд на рабочем сайте, вотом в админке
>   поменять адрес сайта, потом снова сделать дамп, и сверху залить
>   предыдущий,

О ужас..

Порядок действий (всё уже на локальном, а не рабочем!):
1. Заливаешь РОДНОЙ дамп в локальную базу.
2. Переносиш файлы ВП и меняешь в конфиге данные конекта к базе. На локальный сайт не заходишь!!!!
3. Заливаешь скрипт на локальный домен.
4. Скриптом меняешь ПУТИ к файлам.
5. Скриптом меняешь вхождения домена. Осторожно, учитывая разные формы использования - с пртоколом, с/без www, с последним слешем, в мылоадресах и тд.
6. Профит!

Но гораздо проще и безопаснее использовать плагины для миграции. Напр дубликатор https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/

И главное! Никаких SQL-запросов в базу. Миграции либо скриптом, либо плагинами.

Comment: Насчет:  Заливаешь РОДНОЙ дамп в локальную базу. В нем нужно менять url сайта или оставить прежним и через скрипт поменяется?

Comment: А п5 про что? Заливаешь КАК ЕСТЬ, без изменений. Меняется всё скриптом.

Comment: Так и не получилось скриптом нифига заменить, и с http:// прописывал и без него, короче просто залил на локалку как есть, отрубился от инета на всякий и в админке поменял адрес, вроде проканало, но теперь при включеном инете не хочет этот сайт открывать по старому адресу, автоматом правится в строке на локальный))) Только через MS Edge работает. да и хрен с ним, мне хватило поработать)) Это супер-пупер навороченная тема с envato с кучей сериализированных данных, видимо поэтому проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

С базой `MySQL` для `WordPress` я, например, работаю следующим образом.

### Создание дампа

```
mysqldump -Q --max-allowed-packet=1M --extended-insert=false -u DBUser -p DBName > db_dump.sql
```

Ключи `-Q --max-allowed-packet=1M --extended-insert=false` не обязательны, разумеется, но могут помочь на загруженном хостинге.

После `-p` можно без пробелов указать пароль.

### Импорт дампа

```
mysql -uDBUser -p DBName < db_dump.sql
```

### Смена URL на сайте

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://domain.ru', 'http://newdomain.ru') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://domain.ru','http://newdomain.ru');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://domain.ru', 'http://newdomain.ru');
```

После этого можно поискать старый домен в базе и исправить руками, но сайт уже должен работать корректно.

Comment: Во как, круто. Только я не шарю куда всё это прописывать))) Прошу прощения, не указал сразу что нуб в этом плане.

Comment: @Webear `mysqldump` и `mysql`: программы, которые должны быть установлены на сервере. Рекомендую Вам познакомиться с работой с сервером при подключении по протоколу SSH. В другом случае Вы можете воспользоваться какой-либо программой для подключения к базе данных. Если вы используете `phpMyAdmin`, то выбрав нужную базу данных, Вы можете вставить команды обновления домена во вкладке **SQL**.

Comment: Ответ правильный, но: 1. Не работает на shared хостингах. 2. Не работает с сериализованными данными. Никакие слайдеры, опции тем так не поправить. Т.е  для 90% современных сайтов это решение не годится.

Comment: @KAGGDesign не знаю что может не заработать на шареде в данном случае. Видимо мне повезло найти с первого раза тот хостинг, который успешно справляется. Остальные данные (если осталось) правятся либо руками, либо дополнительными командами в базу. На своей практике проблем с переносом базы еще не встречал :)

Comment: 1. И как на shared хостинге выполнить консольную команду linux (mysqldump, mysql)? Да никак. 2. Практика, значит, слабая. Вот примеры из базы данных одного сайта. а) `INSERT INTO `wp_iphorm_form_entries` (...) VALUES 
(... , 'http://millersoils.ru/test/' ...);`- не работают ваши рекомендации, если есть кастомные таблицы. б) `INSERT INTO `wp_layerslider` (...) VALUES (5, 2, 'Road Cars', '', '{\"properties\":{\"post_taxonomy\":\"0\"
... "http:\\/\\/millersoils.ru\\/wp-content\\/uploads\\/2015\\/06\\/a.gif\"...)` - не работают ваши рекомендации со слайдерами и сериализованными данными.

Comment: Эти рекомендации годятся только для примитивных сайтов на WP, которые не пишут сериализованные данные в базу. А попытка таким вот образом делать замены в сериализованных данных приведет к разрушению базы, с вероятностью чуть более, чем 100%.

Comment: В базе, которую я пример для примера выше, свыше 5000 вхождений строки с url сайта. И это небольшой сайт совсем. `После этого можно поискать старый домен в базе и исправить руками` - ну да, конечно.

Comment: _как на shared хостинге выполнить консольную команду, Практика, значит, слабая_ :D

Comment: Вы не путаете shared hosting с VPS? Похоже, путаете. И практика - да, слабая. Слайдеры установлены? - не работают ваши рекомендации. Плагины с кастомными постами или таблицами - не работают рекомендации. WooCommerce установлен - не работают.

Comment: Открою секрет, на шаредах тоже частенько бывает ssh. Потому что это удобно. Я дал начальные рекомендации. Это не значит, что человек скопировав эти строчки 100% получит нужный результат. Разработчики и получают деньги за то, что своей головой думают. Я, если что, отстранюсь от этого "диалога", а то мне стыдно уже и за Вас и за себя, что поддался и стал отвечать. Благодарю Вас за оставленное мнение.

Comment: За меня стыдиться не надо - лишняя трата эмоций.

Comment: Не сритесь, ребят, зачем оно вам надо? Спасибо большое за ответы, я очень признателен. Решил проблему простым заливом на локалку и заменой в админке url'a на нужный. И хоть с этим пришли новые траблы, но мне этого хватило поработать.